# Measure average resource utilization of docker containers from jmeter

Tags: docker, jmeter, performance-testing

I'm doing a performance testing for a server, which deployed on docker containers (have three docker containers). I'm using jmeter to conduct performance testing.

How can I get the average resource utilization of three docker containers into jmeter during the testing time??

Comment: check this...https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/make-use-of-docker-with-jmeter-learn-how

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're trying to achieve from simplest to the most complex:

1. [`docker stats`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stats/) command
2. Special solutions for docker containers health monitoring like [cAdvisor](https://hub.docker.com/r/google/cadvisor/)
3. Special solutions for JMeter for monitoring remote servers like:

   - [PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/)
   - [SSHMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-monitor-server-resource-utilization-with-jmeters-sshmon-listener/)
4. [APM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_performance_management) tools like [AppDynamics](https://www.appdynamics.com/) or [Dynatrace](https://www.dynatrace.com/)